# the set of points where f is continuous is in Borel

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, continuity

For a function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, let $C$ be the set of points where $f$ is
  continuous.  Prove that $C$ is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

I know that for $A=\{f(x): f(x)<a\}$ is open for each real number a, and since openness is preserved by continuity, the set  $f^{-1}(A)\cap C$ should also be open. But I don't know how to write a rigorous proof for it.And I feel I need to write $C$ in such a way so it is clear that it can be written as a union or intersection of open sets.

Comment: It should be $A=\{x: f(x)<a\}$

Answer (score 3):

We can actually show that these points are a $G_{\delta}$ set (countable intersection of open sets).

Let

$$A_n=\{t \ \mathrm{s.t} \ \  \exists \delta_t>0 \  \mathrm{with} \  |f(y)-f(x)|< \frac{1}{n} \ \mathrm{when} \ x,y \in (t-\delta_t, t+\delta_t)\}$$

Each of these $A_n$ are open. The set of points at which $f$ is continuous is $\cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you, and I also want to ask how do we prove that $A_n$ are open?

Comment: I made an error in my initial response when defining $A_n$... It should be more clear now I believe. In order to show that the set is open, directly use the definition of open set: pick a point $x$ and see that $(x-\delta_x, x+\delta_x)\in A_n)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. A point $x$ is a continuity point if $\lim_{y→ x} f(y) = f(x)$. Hence the set of continuity points is 
$$ S = \left\{ x: \lim_{y→ x} f(y) = f(x) \right\} $$
We know how to express $\lim_{y→ x} f(y) = f(x)$ as $∀ ε>0,\dots$ we can then turn '$∀$'s into '$∩$'s and '$∃$'s into '$∪$'s, and conclude with the density of the rationals.

Comment: I am afraid this will not suffice: using the density of rationals in the real line will restrict $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then $f(x)=\mathbb{1}\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @Gabriel but I didn't mean to take a limit along rational points. I did mean what the other answer is using; in the usual definition of continuity, the $\epsilon$ parameter is the size of the error. In the higher voted answer, the choice $\epsilon = 1/n$ is used. I just allowed for more of them. Sorry for the confusion (and for being terse)